# Matlab matrix of images, size issue

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix of `m.n` images like the following:

```
images = zeros( m, n, height, width );
```

It means I have `m.n` images whose width and height is given. Then, in a for loop; I fill these images like:

```
for i=1:m
    for j=1:n
       images(i,j,:,:) = imread('imagePath');
    end
end
```

Then, let's say I want to use the image `(1,1)`:

```
image1 = images(1,1,:,:);
```

I expect this `image1` to have `size = (h,w)`. However, when I say:

```
size(image1)
```

I get the result:

```
(1,1,h,w)
```

## Questions:

### 1.

Why I don't have the following result?

```
(h,w)
```

### 2.

How can I reconstruct my code to have my expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [squeeze](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/squeeze.html) function to do just that :)

```
image1 = squeeze(image1);
size(image1)
```

should give

```
(h,w)
```

Comment: It works great now. Thanks a lot! I was struggling with it for more than 3 hours.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with how matlab does indexing.  When you say

```
image1 = images(1,1,:,:);
```

You're telling matlab you want a 4 dimensional array, with first and second dimensions of size 1.

Where as, if you had said:

```
junk = images(:,:,1,1);
size(junk)
> [m,n]
```

Matlab treats a matrix of size [m,n] the same as if it were of size [m,n,1] or [m,n,1,1].  Can't do that on the front, thus the need for `squeeze` as @Junuxx points out.  An alternative approach is to do thing as follows:

```
images = zeros( height, width, m, n );
for i=1:m
    for j=1:n
       images(:,:,m,n) = imread('imagePath');
    end
end
image1 = images(:,:,1,1);
```

Comment: Hmmm, very interesting ... Thanks for the comment. However, as a C, C++ developer it seems little awkward to me.

Comment: @zagy that's the joy of learning new languages.  It always requires you to wrap (some may say warp) your mind around the new concepts to use the language efficiently.